# How to put Rendezvous function in jmeter thread or vuser for a paticular function

Tags: multithreading, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, threadgroup

I am new in Jmeter , I am familiar with LR. But not able to get some functionalities in jmeter for "VUser/Thread Group ".

1. While I am running my script with **10 threads** in jmeter , what does that mean ([image: Question 1]) :-

> all 10 users are performing same action at same time

or

> each thread is performing separate actions

or

> once one thread complete then another thread will start its execution.

2. How to put 'Rendezvous' function in jmeter for some particular transaction or action like we used write `lr_rendezvous("R1");` in Loadrunner to hit all vusers at same time. Is that possible in Jmeter then how ?

Answer (score 2):

If you set number of thread as 10 its loadrunner equalent as executing with 10 virtual users. all threads will start executing at same time.

You can use Synchronizing_Timer for achieving Rendezvous in JMeter

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer
https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer

Comment: I have 3 Transactions, and started load testing with 50 user, I want all 50 users to hit first/second and third transaction at same time one after another, means for first transaction all 50 user will hit the first page at time after finishing that transaction will do same for second transaction and like that, for that where i have to define the synchronized timer block, and how .

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the 1st part,
'running script with 10 threads' means that they would all start running at the same time... IF ramp-up time == 0.

If you set ramp-up to [someValue] - the threads will get asynced. See the [article from jmeter docs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html).

> Each thread will execute the test plan in its entirety and completely independently of other test threads. Multiple threads are used to simulate concurrent connections to your server application.
>
> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the
>   full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up
>   period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10
>   threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds
>   after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a
>   ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be
>   delayed by 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reproducing human behavior a full rendezvous event, more than one person in the same section of code at the same time engaging in the same function, is exceedingly rare....on the order of a credit card company having only 4-5 people in such an incident on the largest shopping day of the year.

So, if you are headed down this path, consider if you are trying to reproduce human behavior or if you have a technical metric you are hitting with a small number of focused users on such an event.

The use of exceptionally highlighted rendezvous use on a resume is a mark of someone you do not want to hire.